# Add content if element is not empty

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="parent"> 
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"><p>Div with content<p></div> 
  <div class="child"><img scr="pic.png" alt="Div with picture" /></div>
</div>
```

Result I want:

```
<div id="parent"> 
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"><h1>title</h1><p>Div with content<p></div> 
  <div class="child"><h1>title</h1><img scr="pic.png" alt="Div with picture" /></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(".child").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html != '')
        $(this).prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
});
```

Result with my jQuery code:

```
<div id="parent"> 
  <div class="child"><h1>title</h1></div> 
  <div class="child"><h1>title</h1><p>Div with content<p></div> 
  <div class="child"><h1>title</h1><img scr="pic.png" alt="Div with picture" /></div>
</div>
```

So I just want to add a title to every div of a certain class that's not empty.

Comment: Do you care about text nodes, or only elements?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$(".child:not(:empty)").prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
```

[jQuery empty selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Comment: This works! It doesn't work with <div class="child">\r\n</div>, but if you remove the break, it does work

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".child").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html())
        $(this).prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
});
```

Comment: use exclamation mark to check not empty `if (!$(this).html())`

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#parent .child").each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).html()).length > 0 )
        $(this).prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use length to check instead.

```
$(".child").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().length)
        $(this).prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
});
```

Comment: That would fail when the `.child` element contains child elements but no text (e.g. an `img` element).

Comment: @JamesAllardice, Good Point, Please see the update and review your vote.

Answer (score 0):

You got an unclosed `<p>` and to get the selector's html, you use a function, not an attribute :

```
$(this).html()
```

your fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/bCKGV/

mine
http://jsfiddle.net/bCKGV/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(".child:not(:empty)").prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
```

OR:

```
$("#parent .child").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html())
        $(this).prepend('<h1>title</h1>');
});
```

Comment: Oops! okay, could just use a `not` to check if the element is empty or not.
`$(".child:not(:empty)").prepend('<h1>title</h1>');`

Corrected the answer